# android getlastknownlocation always null in emulator

Tags: java, android

It seems a common issue, but i really can't understand why is it happening even though i read ton of simialr issues.

I am playing with a basic location class on a emulator device, i set everything - permissions (FINE and COARSE) , i have set the coordinates in the DDMS i also tried using the telnet and then <geo fix ...> , but no matter what it always crashes witth nullpointer exception on the line with getlastknownlocation, any ideas whats wrong here ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private static LocationManager ok;
private Location L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ok=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(ok.GPS_PROVIDER);
    L=ok.getLastKnownLocation(ok.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location Loc) {
    try {
        double latop=Loc.getLatitude();
        double longe=Loc.getLongitude();
        
        Log.i("OK", "and"+longe+""+latop);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong here (e.g. not checking which providers are enabled or available before trying to get location) that could cause your error. However, I'm going to recommend you read [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) on how to get user location first. Because of the number of changes required to make your current code work it may be more efficient to start over.

Comment: getlastknownlocation will return null if there is no last known location, you need to check if you have a lastknowlocation if not call an update. I never try location with the emulator because I really thing you need to do something that make it work as a normal phone with the location service enabled. So my guess is you are always getting null because you are using the emulator. Also GPS works really fine in the outside, inside in your home maybe could fail and will not provide you a location.

Comment: how emulator will give location value.for testing we have to use the default latlong for emulator which is inside ddms-emulatorcontrol.you have to use device for getting location value..

Comment: sorry, but i have played a lot with location on the devices , so i know some stuff, the link you provided is for Google Play Services exclusevily , also the GPS_PROVIDER is enabled with geo fix , which i already did

Comment: Where is your `requestLocationUpdates()` call? If you do not have one, that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: hi CommonsWare, i tried using requestLocationUpdates as well, but then it will give me NuullPoiner on that one as well ;(

Comment: @CommonsWare, after playing some with the code more ,it turn out that was the key :))) ,can you put that as an answer so that i can give you points ? thank you very much !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` will return `null` in general, if no app has requested a location fix from your desired provider recently.

On the emulator, it seems to take it one step further: you do not get a location unless one has been delivered to the emulator since your app has called `requestLocationUpdates()`.

The general pattern for using `getLastKnownLocation()`, if you want decent odds of getting an actual `Location`, is to use `requestLocationUpdates()` and `removeLocationUpdates()` to ensure that `LocationManager` is actively seeking locations via your chosen provider. Of course, you could also use `LocationListener` and `onLocationChanged()`, rather than `getLastKnownLocation()`, if you so chose.

Answer (score 4):

**Android `getlastknownlocation` is null on emulator**

[@CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586537/4770877) is clear. To get not-null on emulator go to `Google Maps` application and after that you get some location

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, to create your own provider using locationManager.addTestProvider(); so you can make your own tests.

Answer (score 0):

### requestLocationUpdates + getLastLocation

Here, is a code sample based on **Commonsware's answer**. I would call `getLocationUpdates()` in `onCreate()` method so that the app gets location update before you call getLastLocation() method.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;

onCreate(Bundle sis){
    super.onCreate(sis);
    getLocationUpdates();
}

public void getLocationUpdates(){
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }
    };
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
}

public void getLastKnownLocation(){
    
       fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("LOCATION", location);
        } else {
            Log.d("LOCATION", "Location is null");
        }
    });

}
```

#### More thoughts on this.

For some this solution would not make sense at all. But if your app does not need constant location updates then this could be a potential solution to get Location immediately. But there will always be pros and cons of this solution.